# Trying to get php tables into pdf format – using jsPDF-auto-table to get the result of php query(multiple records)into a nicely formatted pdf file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm a 'newbie' on stackoverflow but it is a source that I keep coming to regularly for tips.

I've picked up some code from the simple.html file accompanying the jsPDF auto-table plug-in but as it doesn't appear to pick up data from a php generated table.

I am trying to get the data into a format that can be transformed into a nice pdf report - 'with all the trimmings' - ie; page-breaks, headers on each page, alternate row-colours etc.

I've tried to get the data into a form that can be used by the jsPDF autotable but I'm going wrong in that it is just going through the array and keeping the last record and printing that in pdf format. Code shown below.

```
<button onclick="generate()">Generate pdf</button>

<script src="/js//jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','database');

if(!$link)
{
    echo 'Database Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error() ;
    exit;
}

$results=array();

$sql_staff = "SELECT staff_id, staff_firstname, staff_lastname, staff_username, staff_chargerate, staff_lastlogin FROM tblstaff ORDER BY staff_lastname ASC, staff_firstname ASC ";
        $result_staff = mysqli_query($link,$sql_staff);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_staff)){
            $results[0] = $row['staff_id'];
            $results[1] = $row['staff_firstname'] . " " . $row['staff_lastname'];
            $results[2] = $row['staff_username'];
            $results[3] = $row['staff_chargerate'];
            $results[4] = $row['staff_lastlogin'];
            echo json_encode($results);
            $data = json_encode($results);

        }

?>

<script>
    function generate() {
        var head = [["ID", "Staff Name", "Username", "Charge-rate", "Last Log-in"]];
        var body = [
            <?echo $data;?>
        ];

        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.autoTable({head: head, body: body});
        doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
    }
</script>
```

I think that the problem lays around the line `$data = json_encode($results);` but I don't know enough about either PHP or Javascript to determine how the code needs to be altered to produce a full PDF report. Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably related to overwriting the values in the $results array which means you will get one item instead of an array of items. You probably want something like this:

```
  $results = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_staff)){
          $dataRow = array();
          array_push($dataRow, $row['staff_id']);
          array_push($dataRow, $row['staff_firstname'] . " " . $row['staff_lastname']);
          // etc
          array_push($results, $dataRow);
  }
  $data = json_encode($results);
```

Comment: That's different...the result is that I'm getting the header row OK, then the next row contains the first five records with total data - so under ID, I'm seeing the ID, the fullname, the username, the charge-out rate and last login date for the first record, then under the Staff Name column I'm seeing the same details for the next record. - There is only one row showing under the header.

Comment: Dunnit! - I noticed that when I added echo $data - the data was showing an external set of square brackets [] as well as around each row of data. There is also a set of square brackets around var body = [<?echo $data;?>]; - taking these brackets away to leave var body = <?echo $data;?>; results in all the records being displayed - thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: For some unknown reason the pdf report is generated OK when using Chrome, Firefox and Opera but Edge produces a blank page and IE doesn't do anything at all (I'm using a localhost on a Windows 10 computer) - any ideas what I need to do? Is it a setting in jsPDF or IE or Edge or all three?

Comment: I've managed to use a combination of a javascript piece of code (to determine the browser used) and an 'if statement...' to use doc.save("table.pdf"); for Microsoft Edge and doc.output("dataurlnewwindow"); for other browsers - not managed to get anything successful in IE though, so just created an alert message to say "Try another browser!"